# Persisting link to a help page after using function wrapper

Tags: r

I've started programming in R not so long ago, and I faced some discomfort with names of 3rd party functions. Yes, they have documentation, but sometimes a name of a function is abbreviated to the point of non-readability.

I'd like to write a function wrapper for every function, which name is prone to be completely unreadable. And I still want to be able to call help (i.e. by pressing F1 in RStudio).

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Write a package with your wrappers and add a link to the main function help page in the wrapped function documentation.

Comment: Out of interest, what package is that?

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain but I think that writing wrappers is generally *not* a good idea because for anybody *but you*<sup>1</sup> this will make the code *less readable*, even if they’re not familiar with the original library. For one thing, your functions will be completely unsearchable (on Google etc).

In addition, as commented, R doesn’t allow non-packaged functions to carry documentation. You’d need to generate your own wrapper package. Then, inside the package, you can define your aliases as follows:

```
#' @importFrom original_package orig_fct1
readable_function1 = orig_fct1

#' @importFrom original_package orig_fct2
readable_function2 = orig_fct2

# … etc
```

That is, you don’t need to (and *should not*) generate wrapper functions; it is sufficient and better to just define aliases. The `@importFrom` Roxygen directive causes the documentation to be inherited from the original function.

---

<sup>1</sup> And “anybody but you” includes yourself in a few months’ time!

Comment: Reinforcing the _"this is not a good idea and your future self will definitely not be happy with you"_ sentiment. Cryptic or not, learn the names or use an IDE that makes it easier to see descriptions as you tab complete fully qualified functions. (e.g. `pkgname::functionname`)